# Object/array passing in the RouteParams via Routing angular2

Tags: angular

Working on Routing in angular2. actually i know we can send key/value using RouteParams in the routing but i want to send whole object/array in the RouteParams, i don't know is it possible or not. is there any way to do so if not then any alternate who knows ?

my current HTML part is :

```ts
<div *ngFor="#books of getBooks_array #i=index">
    <a [routerLink]="['/IssueBook', {name: books.book_name, isbn: books.book_ISBN,author: books.book_author, price: books.book_price, id: books.book_id, language: books.book_language}]"></a>
</div>
```

my current .ts conatins:

```ts
constructor(@Inject(RouteParams) params:RouteParams, @Inject(Http) http:Http){
        this.name= params.get('name');
        this.id= params.get('id');
        this.language= params.get("language");
        this.price= params.get("price");
        this.author= params.get("price");
        this.isbn= params.get("isbn");
}
```

but i want to send RouteParams like this :

```ts
<div *ngFor="#books of getBooks_array #i=index">
<a [routerLink]="['/IssueBook', {data: books}]">Books</a>
</div>
```

and i am trying to get data like this:

```ts
constructor(@Inject(RouteParams) params:RouteParams, @Inject(Http) http:Http){
        this.data= params.get('data');
}
```

but i am getting error :

[image]

Comment: What happends when you change the routeconfig to:

`{path:'/ListGridView/List-View/:data', name: 'IssueBook', component: IssueBookComponent}`

?

Comment: Why don't you just stringify each `book`?

Comment: You can serialize your object With JSON.stringify    ( {data: JSON.stringify(books)}  .. but it's not a good idea
Routers params are intented to be url params  ( integers , strings )  .. so it's not a good idea to serialize a hole Object

Comment: If the book_id is unique, just send that, then have your new route get the book data from a service.

Comment: @MarkRajcok yes i can this way but due to some reasons i have to send whole data via Params.

Comment: @MouradZouabi i think JSON.stringify does't make any sense if i suppose i can send serialize data then we also can send simple object too ? is't it ?

Comment: @EricMartinez i don't get you properly i think will you properly explain what you want to say ?

Comment: @PierreDuc i think this syntax is just for setting custom URL m i right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass Objects to Url's in Angular2, but it's not really supported. The get-Method on routeParams only returns a string-representation, so you would get a string like "[Object]".
If you want to access the passed data, you need to use the params-Property:

```
constructor(@Inject(RouteParams) params:RouteParams, @Inject(Http) http:Http){
    this.data= params.params.data;
}
```

But beware, this only works properly the first time you call the route. 
If you call the route anothertime with different data, it can happen that `params.params.data` returns your old data although you put new data into the route.

Comment: than why to use if it only works for first time ? btw what is this second `params` in `params.params.data` ?

Comment: I use it for "one-time" routes, like from a "Create"-Page to an "Overview" to pass data. The Second params is the Params-Map of the RouteParams object, where all passed params are held

Comment: ohh okay but i don't think this is too much beneficial for normal use because we have to load page again and again instead of one time, still thanks for answer

Comment: If you want to share data several times between routes, the only solution that really works is using a common service that holds the data.