# How to pass the value from one page to another in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have 3 links, when I click on any link I move to other page:

```
this.nav.setPages([this.nav.first(), NextPage]);
```

How to pass the value from one page to another, depending on the link clicked?

Comment: This question seems pretty unclear. What is `nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inject Router in your constructor:

```
constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

and in function where you want to trigger nav, you use:

```
this.router.navigate(['./NextCmp', {param: 3}])
```

than in NextCmp you will inject:

```
constructor(public params: RouteParams) { params.get('param'); }
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/y3xa2SCGpGlCu4HxhNY8?p=preview

Comment: can i send object/array in the RouteParams ?

Comment: No, but you always can serialize - deserialize it.

Comment: serialize/deserialize for object or for something else ? i cant get you properly. if you know the answer please answer here    http://stackoverflow.com/q/34432886/5043867

Comment: One guy answered there: { param: JSON.stringify(object)} you can use that.  I don't think so that you can send anything more trough url than strings or numbers, that is logical. What are you trying to send to another route? Can you use localStorage or any other persistent storage?

Comment: yes logically i have to send string or numbers only but according to requirements i have to send object in URL.  when i am sending `json.stringify(object)` angular will throw error `object of undefined` ? i want to send whole object via routeParams.  No i can't use local storage or any other storage. too confused !!! any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try literally JSON.stringify(object)? I meant something like ```{param: JSON.stringify({name: "Smith", age: 23})}```, than at destination: ```JSON.parse( params.get('param'))```

Or, you can even hash it: ```{param: window.btoa(JSON.stringify({name: "Smith", age: 23}))}```, and at destination: ```JSON.parse(window.atob( params.get('param')))```

Comment: yes i have tried above both methods but still unsuccesfull :( still angular throwing error `stringify of undefined` .

Comment: amazing same code i have used but not working...well thanks alot for the help !!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your function code:

```
this.router.parent.navigate(['/PreviousDetailsCmp' {value1:abc, value2:xyz}]);
```

and where you want to use this param value inject RouteParams:

```
 constructor(public params: RouteParams){
        this.val1 = params.get('value1')
        this.val2 = params.get('value2')
    }
```