# angular2 RouteParams, serialization, and complex objects or arrays

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to pass an object as a RouteParam

`let params = { 
    account: 'revenue', 
    page: 3, 
    conditions: [{foo: 'john'}, {foo: 'kelly'}]  // <-- Complex object
}
this._router.navigate(['Journal', params])`

but I am getting a URL like

`http://localhost:3000/journal/revenue/3?conditions=[object%20Object],[object%20Object]`

IIRC, angular1 supported this type of serialization back and forth using JQuery's $.param (I might be wrong)

Is there a way to achieve similar in angular2?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34432886/5043867

Answer (score 1):

Because such parameters are passed within the URL, you could convert them as string using for example `JSON.stringify` and convert them to object from route params using `JSON.parse` when you want to access them.

```
let params = { 
  account: 'revenue', 
  page: 3, 
  conditions: JSON.stringify("[{foo: 'john'}, {foo: 'kelly'}]") 
};
this._router.navigate(['Journal', params]);
```

and

```
constructor(params:RouteParams) {
  var conditions = JSON.parse(params.get('conditions'));
}
```

The other approach is to use a shared service. You set the object into a property of this service before calling the route and get it from the component corresponding to the route after it was activated. You can notice that a shared service needs to be defined when bootstrapping your application to be able to share a single instance for the whole application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 passing object via route params possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478994/angular-2-passing-object-via-route-params-possible)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it looks like it'd work; however, this is such a common use case, I can't imagine this is the _right_ way to do it.

Comment: I'm thinking a combo of $.param and http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't allow for bookmarkable links that way, which is what I'm aiming to do (without any server state I might add)

Comment: will it work for stuff like `[ ',,' , ',,' ]` or `{"hey": "{{{{{"}`?